# Issue resolving data with ActivatedRouteSnapshot and Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-activatedroute

I have an issue with observables in Angular 2. 
I can retrieve data from a DB using a service and can  console.log the data in my service and resolver files, but I am unable to pass the data into my component.

I am using a service to query a database:

```js
getExamQuestion(query) {
  return this.http.get('api/question/1/1').pipe(tap(data => {
    console.log("questiondata", data)  // This logs the expected data
  }));
}
```

```js
constructor(
      private examdataservice:ExamdataService){
    }
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

      return this.examdataservice.getExamQuestion(route.params).pipe(tap(data => {
    console.log("questiondata", data)  // This logs also the expected data
  }));
     
    }
```

My component has the following code, but I am unable to retrieve the data from the service/resolver:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.qData = this.route.snapshot.data['ExamResolver']
    console.log("data", this.qData) // This logs 'undefined'
  }
```

How can I get my component to access the resolved data?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,  I had the following path defined in my app routing module: {
    path:'examquestions/:id/:qid',
    component:ExamquestionsComponent,
    resolve:{exam:ExamResolver}
  }        I had been referencing the actual resolver. I have made the change but it now returns null instead of undefined, despite the data being present in the console.log statements in the service and resolver. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your route to make your resolved data accessible in your component. For example, you should have a route to your component like this :

```
{
  path: 'path/to/your/component',
  component: YourComponent,
  resolve: {
    examQuestions: YourResolver
  }
}
```

And then you can access data in your component :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.qData = this.route.snapshot.data['examQuestions'];
    console.log("data", this.qData); // This logs 'undefined'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer question was the correct solution! All sorted now! Thanks again!